# FB login with devise

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, oauth, openid, facebook-login

I am using devise in my rails app and doing FB login via oauth

I am successful in doing login from laptop but not through chrome android

Error url is https://m.facebook.com/v2.11/dialog/oauth?client_id=1709176549128219&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fconsiliumnsit.herokuapp.com%2Fusers%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=public_profile%2Cemail&state=c96b3d4ce6d9afd513a8239307092ef7be4c6a2c6888765b

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you created your app in [facebook developer console](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/) you added a redirect uri.  The request you are currently sending is coming from a url that you have not currently added.   Go edit your project and add it

```
http://consiliumnsit.herokuapp.com/users/auth/facebook/callback
```

its on the left `facebook login -> settings` look for `Valid OAuth redirect URIs` you can add more then one